# Exclude a category name using cat name

Tags: categories

I'm trying to exclude a category because I have a post that i have in multiple post. How do I like for example I have a post in the categories lastest news and pictures but I want to exclude latest news and show only the pictures name. I tried using $category = get_the_category();  echo $category[0]->cat_name; but that's no help.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I fingered it out this code worked.

```
<?php
//edit below for categories you want excluded
$exclude = array("Latest News", "Uncategorized");
//how do you want the list separated? just a space is okay
$separator = " | ";
//don't edit below here!
$new_the_category = '';
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
if (!in_array($category->cat_name, $exclude)) {
$new_the_category .= '<a href="'.get_bloginfo(url).'/'.get_option('category_base').'/'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</a>'.$separator;
}
}
echo substr($new_the_category, 0, strrpos($new_the_category, $separator));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query(); $recentPosts->query('cat=-3'); //-3 makes sure it shows all categories except for ID number 3
        while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); 

the_title();
the_content();        

endwhile;
```

Would something like this Work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

```
<?php
$category = get_term_by( 'name', 'lastest news', 'category' );
$args = array (
    'tax_query' => array (
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category->slug,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
query_posts($args);
```

This example need WP 3.1 to work. See more: [Taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).